# How to change property values in a IList<T>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

```
 Public class temp()
 {
     int code;
     string name;
  }

  IList<temp> res="assume is has a list of values"

  public void modify<T>(ref Ilist<T> list)
  {
       list[0].code=0;
       list[0].name="";
  }
```

i was getting an error "list does not contain a definition for code/name" . is there any way to change the values in IList

Answer (score 0):

You current example does not makes much sense.

But one way is to constraint your method's generic type parameter to some interface like:

```
public interface ITemp
{
   int code { get; set; }
   string name {get; set;}
}
```

and your specific types would be inheriting it with some implementation

```
public class Temp : ITemp
{
     // implementation
}
```

and then you can write a generic method :

```
public void modify<T>(ref IList<T> list) where T : ITemp
{
   list[0].code=0;
   list[0].name="";
}
```

But this should be done only when you have multiple classes with some common properties and you need a generic method to do some work on those.